# Flex mx:Canvas label is seen null

Tags: flash, canvas, apache-flex, adobe, accordion

The problem is that when the label is not fit the size of accordion, the end of the label is seen as "Hello, my name inull" instead of "Hello, my name is Can." I cannot wide the size of the accordion due to other component size.
It can be seen as "Hello, my name is..", however I cold not find a solution.
I tried the truncateToFit="true" tag but I think it is not used here.
Here is the flex code;

```
   <mx:Accordion x="0" y="2" width="200" height="100%" id="accSettings" styleName="accordionStyle">
            <mx:Canvas id="emptyCanvas" visible="false" includeInLayout="false">
            </mx:Canvas>
        </mx:Accordion>
        <mx:VBox visible="false" width="100%">
 <mx:Canvas id="screenToVMTab" label="Hello, my name is Can!" width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" verticalGap="0" id="vbScreenToVMTab" >
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:VBox>
```

Also, tried to remove height and width tags, not fixed.
Thank you!

Comment: I see visible property of VBox is false. So you won't see Canvas screenToVMTab. Can you add a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<mx:Accordion left="2" top="2" width="130" bottom="2" id="accSettings" styleName="accordionStyle">
    <mx:Canvas id="emptyCanvas" label="Empty Canvas" visible="true" includeInLayout="true" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Label text="Inside Empty Canvas." />
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas id="screenToVMTab" label="Hello, my name is Can!" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" verticalGap="0" id="vbScreenToVMTab" >
            <mx:Label text="Inside VBox. Label 1"/>
            <mx:Label text="Inside VBox. Label 2"/>
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Accordion>
```

[image]